# How to bring favourites in entry address bar in Safari

Tags: safari, macos

Yosemite has brought a new feature in safari which is bring favourite when we click any *filled address bar*. 
[image]

But the favourite webpages don't popup when we click an empty address bar. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to bring the favourite popup below the address bar for a new/empty tab.

Comment: Are you in these requirements ? http://macs.about.com/od/OS-X-Yosemite/fl/OS-X-Yosemite-Minimum-Requirements.htm

Comment: @MrMojoRisin no.

Comment: So I think that you are not able to use this features...

Comment: I am just not able to bring the FAVOURITE window, when I click the blank address bar.